# Метод работает в IDE, но не работает при запуске через cmd

Tags: java, cmd

Создал метод `getPid()`, который выдаёт PID процесса по его названию. 
Программа при работе через CMD (`java -cp . Test`) всегда выдаёт 0, но при работе через IDE всё просто шикарно. Возможно, проблема заключается в русских символах, которые буфер получает на вход? У меня просто нет больше идей.

```
public static long getPID(String taskname) {

    try {

        Process tasklistProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq " + taskname + "\"" });

        BufferedReader tasklistOutputReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(tasklistProcess.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;
        long pid=0;

        while ((line = tasklistOutputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);

                if (line.contains(taskname + " ")) {

                    pid = Long.parseLong((line.replace(taskname,"")).trim().split(" ")[0]);
                    break;
                }

        }

        return pid;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Вот что выдаёт cmd при вводе  `cmd /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq skype.exe"`
[image: cmd]

А вот, что выдаёт IDE при вызове метода `System.out.println(getPID("Skype.exe"));`
с незакоментированной строкой `System.out.println(getPID("Skype.exe"));` внутри метода `getPID`.
[image: ide]

Comment: А что в `taskname` передаётся?

Comment: System.out.println(getPID("process.exe"));

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что процесса этого попросту нет. Проверьте из командной строки вашу команду. Она что-то возвращает?

Comment: Как раз-таки при вызове метода из класса, запущенного через cmd - ничего не возвращает. А при вызове через IntelliJ IDEA всё работает отлично, т.е. PID не равен 0 и с полученным PID отлично сочетается мой метод taskKill(long pid), который этот процесс убивает. И для IDE и для cmd запускается один и тот же код, 100%.

Comment: Запустите команду, которая образуется из этой строки прямо из CMD `cmd", "/c", "tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq " + taskname`. Без Java.

Comment: При вводе:
    cmd /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq skype.exe"
получаю 4 строчки в консоли. Последняя - это, собственно, отфильтрованный процесс скайпа.

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить в вопрос вывод `cmd /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq skype.exe`? У меня ваш метод работает.

Comment: Ваш код заходит в `if`? Поставьте туда какой-нибудь вывод на экран.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил вывод cmd и ide. Да, передаю с заглавной буквы аргумент. 
>У меня ваш метод работает.
Он у вас работает в IDE? Или не выдаёт 0 при вызове getPID("Skype.exe"); через cmd?

Comment: Он у меня работает и в cmd и в IDE. Но ОС у меня на англ. Ваш код заходит в if statement? Он находит там строку Skype.exe?

Comment: Нет, до строки   if (line.contains(taskname + " ")) {   дело не доходит. Как я и говорил в начале, проблема наверняка в русских символах. Выяснил, что код не идёт дальше while (statement), то есть до объявления цикла println нормально выводится, а после условия - нет. Значит проблема начинается здесь: while ((line = tasklistOutputReader.readLine()) != null) {

Comment: Запусти `tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh` чтобы получить список в формате CSV, который проще разобрать: "Skype.exe","2612","Console","1","68 652 КБ"

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась сносом java и jdk с дальнейшей переустановкой в одну директорию Program Files/Java. Так же в ходе этого действа выяснилось, что версия jdk была 1.7, а не 1.8, как сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static long getPID(String taskname) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","tasklist","/FI", "IMAGENAME eq "+taskname);
        final Process process = builder.start();
        long pid = 0;
        try {

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains(taskname + " ")) {

                    pid = Long.parseLong((line.replace(taskname, "")).trim().split(" ")[0]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (final Exception ignored) { }


        return pid;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: После полного сноса Java и JDK и установки их в одну директорию всё заработало. До этого стояли на разных дисках в целях экономии места на SSD. Так же JDK был версии 1.7, а не 1.8 . Как итог - мой код начал работать и в cmd. Извините за отнятое время =) Только начал изучение.

Comment: @Exide, всё в порядке. Вот, учимся вместе. Я вот даже не думал в сторону версии. С наступающим  :)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо запуска внешней утилиты можно воспользоваться Win32 API напрямую, получая данные их первоисточника. Ну не совсем конечно напрямую, а с помощь JNA.

```
package jnaps;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;

public class JnaPs {

    interface PsKernel32 extends Kernel32 {
        public final static PsKernel32 INSTANCE = (PsKernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", PsKernel32.class);

        boolean K32EnumProcesses(int[] pProcessIds, int cb, IntByReference pBytesReturned);
        boolean K32EnumProcessModules(WinNT.HANDLE hProcess, WinNT.HANDLE[] lphModule, int cb, IntByReference lpcbNeeded);
        int K32GetModuleFileNameExW(WinNT.HANDLE process, WinNT.HANDLE module, char[] lpFilename, int nSize);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int idsSize = 1024; // Установить достаточно большим. Заранее не известно сколько будет процессов
        final int[] ids = new int[idsSize];
        final IntByReference bytesReturned = new IntByReference();

        // размерчик массива в байтах -------------------------.
        //                                                     |
        if (!PsKernel32.INSTANCE.K32EnumProcesses(ids, idsSize * 4, bytesReturned)) {
            System.err.printf("Ошибка %d EnumProcesses\n", Native.getLastError());
            return;
        }

        int count = bytesReturned.getValue() / 4; // bytesReturned / sizeof(DWORD)
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int pid = ids[i];
            WinNT.HANDLE ph = PsKernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(Kernel32.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | Kernel32.PROCESS_VM_READ , false, pid);
            // Здесь должна быть проверка на INVALID_HANDLE
            try {
                final WinDef.HMODULE[] modules = new WinNT.HMODULE[1]; // нужен только один главный модуль
                final IntByReference needed = new IntByReference();
                // 8 байт на 64bit-ной системе? ----------------------------.
                // Есть ли в JNA определение размеров объектов API?         |
                if (!PsKernel32.INSTANCE.K32EnumProcessModules(ph, modules, 8, needed)) {
                    System.err.printf("Ошибка %d EnumProcessModules для process id: %d\n", Native.getLastError(), pid);
                    continue;
                }                
                final int fileNameMaxSize = 1024;
                final char[] fileNameA = new char[fileNameMaxSize];
                if (PsKernel32.INSTANCE.K32GetModuleFileNameExW(ph, modules[0], fileNameA, fileNameMaxSize) == 0) {
                    System.err.printf("Ошибка %d GetModuleFileNameExW для process id: %d\n", Native.getLastError(), pid);
                    continue;                    
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (char c : fileNameA) {
                    if (c == 0) break; // string terminator (NULL)
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                String fileName = sb.toString();

                // В итоге получили:
                // имя файла -------------------------.
                // id процесса ---------------.       |
                //                            |       |
                System.out.printf("%d %s\n", pid, fileName);
            } finally {
                PsKernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(ph);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Вывод id процесса и название файла (если нет ошибки):

```
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 0
...
4164 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 2076
2408 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 2100
2580 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 2316
4540 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 1204
4640 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe
2920 C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 3188
Ошибка 6 EnumProcessModules для process id: 3804
```

Ошибки на сервисах. Надо как-то по другому извлекать информацию о них. В Windows есть ещё API для работы с процессами.
Если кого-то заинтересует такой вариант, может взять пример использования JNA и сделать полностью рабочее решение для себя.

Comment: Слишком трудный синтаксис для новичка, но я обязательно потом разберу и вникну. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в InputStreamReader добавить необходимую кодировку

```
public static long getPID(String taskname) {

    try {

        Process tasklistProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq " + taskname + "\"" });

        BufferedReader tasklistOutputReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(tasklistProcess.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("cp866")));

        String line = null;
        long pid=0;

        while ((line = tasklistOutputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);

                if (line.contains(taskname + " ")) {

                    pid = Long.parseLong((line.replace(taskname,"")).trim().split(" ")[0]);
                    break;
                }

        }

        return pid;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

в качестве аргумента `Charset.forName("cp866")` передавайте ту кодировку которая используется в вашей консоли. 
Чтобы узнать текущую кодировку консоли, нужно ввести в ней команду `chcp` 
получите примерно такой ответ `Текущая кодовая страница: 866`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь идёт нормальный вывод каждой строки tasklistOutputReader'а в IDE.